# How to limit number of selected friends when send facebook private messages using FBSDKMessengerSharer or FBSDKMessage Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

I want to send message to friends, and find out 2 ways: 
FBSDKMessengerSharer and FBSDKMessageDialog

But I need to limit the number of selected friends before the messages go to the friends inboxes.

For example, I have a list of 500 friends, but for everytime I can only be able to send to 5 friends. When use FBSDKMessengerSharer/FBSDKMessageDialo, I can select as many friends as I want.
How can I do that ? Or I cannt do that?

Cheers.

Comment: You can’t. (And why would you want to do this in the first place? How many people they want to send something to, should be up to the user.)

Comment: thank you, client's needs you know :D